# Is `A a = A()` valid? What operators / methods are invoked underneath?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, language-lawyer, copy-constructor

Given the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
 public:
  int x;

 public:
  A() : x(0) { std::cout << "ctor" << std::endl; }
  A(const A& o) : x(o.x) { std::cout << "copy ctor" << std::endl; }
  A& operator=(const A& o) { x = o.x; std::cout << "copy asgnmt" << std::endl; return *this; }
};

int main() {
  A a = A();
  return 0;
}
```

The above code gets complied with `g++ 4.8.4` on `Ubuntu 14.04`:

```
g++ -g -o test test.cpp
```

And output:

```
ctor
```

Is `A a = A();` compliant with C++ standard(s)? Or is that just UB therefore compiler dependent? If that code is standard compliant then which methods are invoked underneath? `A()` should return nothing at all, shouldn't it?

Comment: Interesting question. Try defining move semantics. It may be using the move assignment operator under the hood.

Comment: `A a = A();` -- Why would you think this is not valid?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie because `A()` is defined to return nothing, right?

Comment: @duong_dajgja An object is constructed.  What *is not* valid is your lack of a `return` in your assignment operator for `A`.  Turn up your compiler warnings.

Comment: @VorpalSword The code gets compiled well without `-std=c++11` option so I think it has nothing to do with `move` operations.

Comment: `A()` is a default constructor call.

Comment: @duong_dajgja -- Consider -- `bool foo(const A& x) { return true; }` and then `int main() { auto b = foo (A()); }` -- So `A()` doesn't "return nothing".

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie That's interesting. Thanks!

Comment: @duong_dajgja -- If you use STL functions such as `std::accumulate`, passing a default constructed initial value is common.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`A()` performs [value initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization), which creates a nameless temporary object.

`A a = A();` is [copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization), `a` is initialized from the above temporary. As you can see from the output, the default constructor of `A` is used to initialize `a` directly here, because of [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision).